# Extension activation failed: "At this time, Copilot is not available in your location. You are currently logged in as

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Установил GitHub Copilot для VSCode вместе с чатом, но как только расширения установились, у меня вместо желаемого ChatGPT под рукой возникла эта ошибка. В аккаунт GitHub я вошёл, последняя версия VSCode и расширений. В чём проблема?

Comment: А как на счет того чтобы закинуть текст ошибки в переводчик ?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не по адресу

Comment: @Air Вопрос актуальный, нужно решение проблемы, а не ее обсуждение. Возможные варианты с проксирование внутри приложения

Comment: @oruchkin, я ни чего не обсуждал. Я просто думаю, что вопрос не по адресу. Переведи заголовок, то бишь выданную ошибку. Зная наших коллег и часто встречаясь с теми или иными ошибками, по практике знаю, что или поленились каждую ошибку обработать и тогда хрен его знает (может что-то иное там, а не регион), что там за проблема.........

Answer (score 0):

Если перевести твою ошибку, то станет ясно, что Copilot не доступен в твоем регионе. Можешь попытаться использовать впн, либо прокси, обычно помогает в таких случаях.